# SQLAlchemy: get max of grouped values

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I have this table in my Flask app:

```
class Events(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    timestamp_event = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
```

I need to get the day with the most events recorded, both the value and the date itself in printable format (such as d/m/y). I am trying:

```
daily_max = db.func.max(db.session.query(db.func.count(Events.id),\
                        db.func.date_format(Events.timestamp_event,'%d/%m/%y'))\
                        .group_by(db.func.date_format(Events.timestamp_event,'%Y%M%D')))
```

and then hopefully daily_max[0] will have the value and daily_max[1] will have the date with no hh:mm:ss

When I print daily_max after the query, the value is:

```
daily_max =  max((SELECT count(events.id) AS count_1, date_format(events.timestamp_event, :date_format_2) 
                  AS date_format_1 
                  FROM events GROUP BY date_format(events.timestamp_event, :date_format_3)))
```

This is data sample. The answer (`daily_max` value) should be **(3, "21/01/2022")**:

```
id   timestamp_event
---- ---------------
1    2022-01-15 12:34
2    2022-01-21 01:23
3    2022-01-21 05:33
4    2022-01-21 11:11
5    2022-01-23 00:01
6    2022-01-23 23:29
```

Any clue on what I´m doing wrong? Couldn´t find the answer in the docs.

Comment: You need to execute the query, for example by adding `.all()` to the end.  Then it will return a list of (date, value) tuples.

Comment: @snakecharmerb: yes, I know how to to that (I have other queries running fine). It´s just that I need to get the max value without doing query.desc.first, if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Ah ok - are you saying that the problem is that the "time" part of the `DateTime` is messing up your `GROUP BY`?  What database are you using?

Comment: I´m using MySQL.  My issue is that I don´t find how to get the max count of events that have happened in one day (one event = one row, many events the same day).  Also retrieve the date that the max happened. I will add a sample datatable to the question now.

Answer (score 0):

This is the awful (inneficient) way:

```
daily_max = db.session.query(db.func.count(Events.id),
            db.func.date_format(Events.timestamp_event,'%d/%m/%y'))\
            .group_by(db.func.date_format(Events.timestamp_event,'%Y%M%D'))\
            .order_by(db.func.count(Events.id).desc()).first()
```

It groups all pairs of (id count, days), sorts the pairs by the count in reverse order, then gets the first pair.

It does the work but I really would like to know the efficient, elegant way using func.max()

Comment: I'm not sure you can do much better than this - however you arrive at the result, the database will have to compute the count for all dates to make sure it gets the correct result.  For large tables, you could build an index over `DATE(timestamp_event)` (or date_format() if you prefer) for example to speed up the query.

Comment: If you want a second opinion (I'm not a MySQL expert), consider asking this as a pure SQL question; how you express the query in SQLAlchemy is just implementation detail.